# Can't send html email using exim

Tags: linux, email, console, mime, exim

I'm trying to send html mail using smarthost with the following command:

```
cat test_mail.txt | mail -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s "title" example@mail.com
```

I have also tried using this:

```
mail  -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s 'title' example@mail.com  < test_mail.txt
```

But it is not possible because I get this error:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0: No such file or directory
```

I'm using exim:

```
dpkg -S `which sendmail`
exim4-daemon-light: /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

My system is Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround. I installed postfix, so mail configuration is like that:

```
dpkg -S `which sendmail`
postfix: /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Then you can send an email using following command:

```
cat mailheader mailbody | sendmail -t
```

where mailheader it is file containing:

```
To: mail@example.com
Subject: Example Subject
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and mailbody it is file with your message.